# Wicket-9: how to prevent the data stored in the session from being cleared after web-container restarting?

Tags: wicket

I've upgrade wicket from 8.12 to 9.5 and after that my application started clearing session data every time I restart tomcat instance. In particular all users have to sign in after that.
With 8.12 version session data persisted between restarting.

How can I configure similar behavior in 9.5 version?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is managed by Wicket.

Wicket uses the HttpSession to store information. Http sessions are managed by the servlet container, like Apache Tomcat, Jetty, etc.

For Apache Tomcat read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/manager.html

Comment: It is, somehow. All I have changed - is version of wicket libraries. And this led to the fact that the data ceased to persist between restarting. I've test this on different environments and tomcat instances (8.5.23, 9.0.27, 9.0.53) and result is the same.

Comment: Did previous versions of wicket (8.12 and earlier) use the HttpSession as storage?

Comment: Yes. Nothing has changed in Wicket related to HttpSession's usage.